# How dynamic add events to a tag in my custom grid component

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

````
<template>
  <tbody>
  <template v-for="(row,index) in datalist">
    <tr @click="rowevent != null?rowevent(row,this.$el):''" :class="index % 2 === 0?bodytrclass[0]:bodytrclass[1]">
      <td v-if="col.show" v-for="col in collist" @click="eventbus(row,$event)" @mouseover="eventbus(row,$event)">
        <template v-if="col.type">
          <component v-for="com in col.type" :is="com" :rowdata="row" :colname="col.colname"
                     :tdcbfun="col.cbfun"></component>
        </template>
        <template v-else>{{ row[col.colname] }}</template>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </template>
  </tbody>
</template>
```
````

now  a question

```
`<tr @click="rowevent != null?rowevent(row,this.$el):''" :class="index % 2 === 0?bodytrclass[0]:bodytrclass[1]">`
```

how can i add events by data (props) ?   dynamic v-on? 
i don't want to write @click @mouseover @.......

i want like this ....

````
```
props: {
  trevent: [{event:'click',eventfun:function (rowdata) {
    if(rowdata.age<10){  //@:click=eventfun(rowdata)
       alert('children')
    }
 }},{event:'mouseover',eventfun:function (rowdata) {
    if(rowdata.age<10){//@mouseover=eventfun(rowdata)
       tip('children')
    }
 }}]
}
```
````

another example  button component

````
```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="eventbus" @mouseover="eventbus">{{options.btnname}}</button>
  </div>
</template>

methods: {
      eventbus: function (rowdata, event) {
        var eventname = event.type
        var eventpos = event.currentTarget.localName

        this.$root.$emit(eventpos + eventname, rowdata)
      }
    }

vm.$on('trclick',function(){
.......do something
})
```
````

if sometime emit not $on  dont do it    ...this kind of  settlement  so .....

and  i also can use component :is   but javaer must write   component   so much
oh  v-if

Sorry for my english..

终于可以写中文了
我们公司正在开发一个公共组件，刚开始做现在正在做表格的组件。
这个组件是通用的，想用在公司的不同的系统上，也是开源的。
麻烦大家帮看看  现在如何可以 根据传入的props 数据 ，动态添加事件到某个标签上？
我找不到办法动态添加v-on
想做的功能多一些  还不想总让研发人员写动态的component
我尽量将vue封装成 jquery那种调用形式，大家都比较容易会。
其次是我现在在mainjs 里把vue写好的组件暴露出来window.$grid = grid.vue  然后在引入webpack打包好的js
然后直接使用  请问还有其他更好的关于把vue做成组件在外部调用的例子吗？
还有如果我这种方式引用的话  是否还能使用vue-router ? 最好给个例子 
最近半个月狂看Vue  在此感谢下尤大弄出这么好的东西！
借这里给大家拜个早年，祝各位在新的一年里身体健康，生活幸福！
英语不好麻烦各位了

Comment: you want to assign the `@click`, `@mouseover` events of the `<tr>` elements from the components code?

Comment: Yes . For example a props event=click  eventfun = function () ...  it can assign the @click  event  on the element

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe not the best concept to modify the event listeners of a components DOM afters it was compiled. If found this quote from [Evan You](https://github.com/yyx990803) (creator of vuejs) [here](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/193):

> I think you are approaching this with wrong assumptions. Templates for a component is static, once it's defined you can't change it. You need to express the parts that may be changed inside the template.

It is possible to [recompile a component template](https://jsfiddle.net/gm4uf485/2/) as [Elfayer](https://github.com/Elfayer) shows [here](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/193), but it does not improve elegancy for this problem since one has to provide a template for every configuration of the properties. For one event attribute it's no problem, you would need two templates. But for three events you would already need 8 templates and so on...

## Option 1: Handle logic within normal event handlers

Use normal event handlers which perform conditional execution of dynamic event listeners.
In your template you could replace

```
<template>
...
    <tr @click="rowevent != null?rowevent(row,this.$el):''" :class="index % ...
...
</template>
```

with:

```
<template>
...
    <tr @click="tr_handler(row,this.$el)" :class="index % ...
...
</template>
```

and then use the `tr_handler()` method to check whether there is an event listener assigned to a certain property or not:

```
methods: { 
   //...
   tr_handler: function(row,e) {
      if (this.rowevent) {
         return this.rowevent(row, e)
      }
   }
   //...
}
```

This approach provides a clean structure and keeps the string template feature of vuejs.

## Option 2: Use a `render()` function

One can render the whole template dynamically by using a [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html). Also it is possible to apply event listeners to the nodes as described within the latter link:

```
on: {
  '!click': this.doThisInCapturingMode,
  '~keyup': this.doThisOnce,
  `~!mouseover`: this.doThisOnceInCapturingMode
}
```

Both approaches do not avoid declaring the event within the template.
[Here is some statement about this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Why-Listeners-in-HTML) which explains how things are done in vue-world.

> Since you don’t have to manually attach event listeners in JS, your
> ViewModel code can be pure logic and DOM-free. This makes it easier to
> test.

Comment: thanks ！Today is the spring festival  I will replay tomorrow .

Comment: Option2 maybe can do it.I try to use render later.Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach could be using the special propr `ref` and adding the event listener in `mounted` lifecycle. since it is added manually, you may want to remove it too, so I would add it in `beforeDestroy` life cycle.

#### Set the ref to the tag

```
<tr ref="my-tag" :class="index % 2 === 0?bodytrclass[0]:bodytrclass[1]">
```

#### Add and Remove the event in the livecycles

```
mounted() {
    this.$refs['my-tag'].addEventListener(this.myEvent,() => {
         // Some logic..
    });
},
beforeDestroy() {
    this.$refs['my-tag'].addEventListener(this.myEvent,() => {
         // Some logic..
    });
}
```

It may not be the nicer approach but would do the trick.